# AWS Cloudformation: ImageId cannot be empty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am using cloud formation to create:

```
load balancer + target-group w/ instance(from custom AMI)
```

I used *create template in designer* and edited their default configs:

> I chose **Elastic Loadbalancer V2** >> **target group**

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "ELBV3LB29NC1": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer",
            "Properties": {
                "IpAddressType" : "ipv4",
                "Name" : "quest-loadbalancer2",
                "SecurityGroups" : [ "sg-036a1a54caee05af5"],
                "Subnets" : [ "subnet-795d4435", "subnet-7d5a5a07" ],
            }
        }
    }
}

// **********************

{
    "Resources": {
        "ELBTV1G4J8KH": {
            "Type": "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup",
            "Properties": {
                "Name": "quest-target-group-2",
                "Port": 80,
                "Protocol": "HTTP",
                "Targets": [
                    {
                        "Id" : "i-0f5c5714bed60786b",
                        "Port" : 80
                    }    
                ],
                "TargetType": "i-0f5c5714bed60786b",
                "VpcId": "vpc-a28dece9"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> An EC2 Instance

```
{
    "Resources": {
        "EC2I5QYZC": {
            "Type": "AWS::EC2::Instance",
            "Properties": {
                "AvailabilityZone" : "us-east-2",
                "InstanceType" : "t2.micro",
                "ImageId" :"ami-034e6c68f4dy6d449",    // <------------ AMI ID 
                "SecurityGroups" : [ "sg-036a1a54caee05af5" ],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **ERROR** : (after clicking create stack) ImageId cannot be empty *and it stops right there*.

Comment: Are you sure the instance is from this place? I more concerned about issues in your target group than the instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target Instance id is an Instance Id. It should be an AMI ID instead.
You're trying to connect to an already existing instance instead of creating a new one.